# updating a table with data from itself

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code.  Using MS sql 2008

```
use gasnominations;
update dbo.TestData
set amendedValue = 
(select amendedvalue
from gasdata
where readDate between DateAdd(Hour, 7, DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, GETDATE()), -2)) 
and dateadd(hour, 6, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -1)))
```

Basically I have a table with several columns one is the date (readdate) and one is amendedvalue and the last one is a ref number.  Every day 350 rows are inserted with an sql job.  So readdate is the date with the hour and for each ref number there are 24 records (one for every hour).  The data is inserted from yesterday at 6am till today at 6am.

I want to create another step in the job that gets the amended values from the day before (so for today which is Monday, it would get the amended value for each hour and ref number from saturday 6am to sunday 6am) and updates the amended values for today (ie sunday 6am to monday 6am)

hope that makes sense.

UPDATE

I have now got to the following but it adds every row from the table which is every day since November 2012.  It does add in the amended value though.

```
         INSERT INTO dbo.testdata (readDate,TagName,Value, amendedValue)
                select a.readDate, a.TagName, a.Value, b.amendedValue                  
                from gasdata a inner join gasdata b on b.TagName = a.tagName COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
and a.readDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, b.readDate)
```

Comment: Try put the question clearer please. Give examples where appropriate.

Comment: On what basis you want to update these rows ? so for SAT 5pm if the value is 90, it should be update in from of row MON 5pm ?

Comment: But you are selecting value from table `gasdata` no?

Comment: yes techdo, I am getting data from gasdata, as I am testing I am using a test table called testdata.  When I make it live I will replace testdata with gasdata.

Comment: Ashutosh Arya - yes thats correct.  Most of the time the data will be null in the amendedvalue column but sometimes it will have a number in it and I need to copy it to the same row but a day later.

Comment: Also you don't get data for sunday, Right ?